# Returning an unresolved promise (async/await) in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I was hoping someone could help me make sense of why the following code isn't working properly.

In the `Expense Data` class, I have a function `listExpenses` which should only return `data` once the promise is either resolved or rejected.

However, when I instantiate a new `expenseData` object and then try to log a list of expenses, I get a pending Promise. I would have expected the Promise to always be resolved at this stage.

```js
class ExpenseData {
  constructor() {
    this.client = new Client({ database: 'expenses' })
  }

  async listExpenses() {
    await this.client.connect().catch(err => logAndExit(err));
    let data = await this.client.query("SELECT * FROM expenses ORDER BY created_on ASC")
                                .catch(err => logAndExit(err))
    return data;
  }
}
```

```js
let expenseData = new ExpenseData(); 
let myData = expenseData.listExpenses();
console.log(myData);
```

Here's what I get in my console after running this code:
`Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: your method is async, but you do not await it.
`let myData = await expenseData.listExpenses();` ?

Comment: `let x = await ...; return x;` behaves the same as `return ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is asynchronous meaning it immediately returns a Promise that will be resolved or rejected depending on what will happen in the method's body.

You need to either do this:

```js
const func = async () => {
  let expenseData = new ExpenseData(); 
  let myData = await expenseData.listExpenses();
  console.log(myData);
};

func();
```

Or this:

```js
let expenseData = new ExpenseData(); 
expenseData.listExpenses().then((myData) => console.log(myData));
```

Comment: Ah yep, you're right. Just tried the first approach and it worked. Makes sense — thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Don't hesitate to mark this as the correct answer. Good luck!